# problem with NVIDIA GP100 running on Ubuntu 16.04.05-desktop

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg

when I run "nvidia-smi", I got the following result:
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

Then, I check the driver installed in my system by the command "dpkg -l | grep -E "nvidia-[0-9]{3}". I got the followings:
rc nvidia-304         304.135-0ubuntu0.16.04.2    amd64     NVIDIA legacy binary driver - version 304.135
ll nvidia-410          410.78-0ubuntu~gpu16.04.1     amd64     NVIDA binary driver - version 410.78

It semms that "nvidia-410" has already been installed. My graphics card is Nvidia Quadro GP100. The Nvidia driver website says 410.78 is correct version for it. However, I cannot install the driver through the package downloaded online. The driver is installed through graphics drivers PPA.

My gcc version is gcc (ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609. The operating system I used is Ubuntu 16.04.05 LTS - desktop.

I checked "Xorg.0.log" file. It shows the error: failed to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module. Then I have no clue how to solve this problem.

I also did the following things that I got the answers online, but I still couldn't log into the GUI.  The system stays on login loop back.

1) reinstall lightdm
2) modify grub to nomodeset
3) Add "nouveau" to blacklist.conf

I have run the nvidia-bug-report.sh. Here is the [Nvidia bug report log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fl31uJJLJIp_UF-9ja49fXduLKf4eOem/view?usp=sharing). Any suggestion is helpful for me.